# Parse SDK for Push Notifications, Compile Errors

Tags: iphone, parsing, sdk, push-notification, parse-platform

Im using the [Parse SDK](https://www.parse.com) in an existing iPhone project. I followed the steps for XCode 3 in the quick start guide, however on compiling I get the following errors. I have no clue as to why they show up. Has anyone encountered & resolved the same issue?
The errors are below:

```
"_objc_release", referenced from:
+[PFViewUtils initialize] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils init] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showOfflineError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showOfflineError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)

"_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue", referenced from:
+[PFViewUtils utils] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)

"_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue", referenced from:
-[PFViewUtils init] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showOfflineError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
-[PFViewUtils showError] in Parse(PFViewUtils.o)
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: are you sure you're linking with Foundation.framework?

Comment: Yes, i double checked the linking of all frameworks mentioned in the quick start guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev support at Parse stated in an email reply that the SDK will work on Xcode4.2 & above. So much for mentioning steps to use on Xcode 3